# Web project with git - access rights & groups

Tags: git, web, production-environment

I have found several posts on SO talking about deploying web projects with git.
Most are not too recent, but there seem to be a [link](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) usually appreciated.

This little tutorial suggests to use the `GIT_WORK_TREE` functionality to allow detaching the remote working tree on the web server directory.

The aim is to be able to `git push web` from the local repository to put modifications directly in production.

What I'm wondering is how should I manage my users/groups in the remote server to allow the deployment.

Mainly 2 questions:

- Is [this tutorial](http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto) still relevant ?
- If yes, which user/group should own the `/var/www/my_project` directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the tutorial should work, but remember that /var/www/my_project is to be writable by the (remote) user who will push the commits since hooks are run with the same uid/gid.

Otherwise, if you need more people to being able to push to the site, you would need them to use another user or to use [gitolite](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) or similar tools.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think it's ok to chown `/var/www/my_project` to a special group that I give to users who need to post ?

Comment: The problem is not the group, but your umask, if files are created 644, no matter which group you choose for your users, they will not be able to modify those files.

Better to use for all the same user, e.g. create 'git' user, maybe with /etc/passwd shell as git-shell, and ask other users for their ssh public key, that you will store it in $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys of that 'git' user.

You will do not lose commit authorship since it is not tied to the 'pusher' user.